# Skipping nested field with Jackson data binding?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

How must I bind (bidirectional) the following json snippet to the Java objects below with Jackson?

I want the key/value pairs of the Json newsletter node to end up in the Map of the newsletter field. 
What must be the Jackson config (annotations and others) to bind this ?
Sorry, I don't know how :( (using the latest version of Jackson).

The Json format below is fixed, I receive it from a third party rest service (I can't change it). I can change the java code, but prefer the setup below.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "newsletter": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
}
```

**The Java Objects:**

```
class Preferences {
    private NewsLetter newsLetter;
    // getter/setter for field newsLetter.
}

class NewsLettter {
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    // getter/setter for field properties.
}
```

Comment: *"The Json format below is fixed, I receive it from a third party rest service"* a third party service generates invalid JSON? Btw, do you need to keep the `NewsLettter` class?

Comment: I like the class NewsLetter, but can remove/modify it if you have a good idea. Hit me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) for deserialization

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static, two-argument method (first argument name of property, second value to set), to be used as a "fallback" handler for all otherwise unrecognized properties found from JSON content.

And [`@JsonAnyGetter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) for serialization.

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static, no-argument method or member field as something of a reverse of `JsonAnySetter` method; basically being used like a getter but such that contents of the returned Map (type must be `Map`) are serialized as if they were actual properties of the bean that contains method/field with this annotations

```
public class Newsletter {

    private final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addProperty(String name, String value) {
        properties.put(name, value);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This should work just fine for your use case.

Test

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json
                = "{\n"
                + "    \"newsletter\": {\n"
                + "        \"key1\": \"value1\",\n"
                + "        \"key2\": \"value2\",\n"
                + "        \"key3\": \"value3\"\n"
                + "    }\n"
                + "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Preferences prefs = mapper.readValue(json, Preferences.class);
        Map<String, String> properties = prefs.getNewsletter().getProperties();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(prop.getKey() + ":" + prop.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Jackson tips: using @JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter to create "dyna beans"](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html)

Comment: thanks. I just used it exactly as you suggest above, and deserialization works fine: the instance contains the map with: "{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}" However, serialization this back to JSON results in: "{"newsLetters":{"emptyProperties":false,"key1":"value1","k
ey2":"value2","key3":"value3"}}" I have no idea where this extra key/value pair "emptyProperties/false" comes from (not mine). Any idea ? Maybe from the @JsonTypeInfo?... I use ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)...

Comment: Yeah I don't know. I just tested with my example above, using `S.o.p(mapper.writeValueAsString(prefs))` and I don't see the extra property. Is `Newsletter` a subclass of some other class that has that property?

Comment: thanks for your quick response. How do you specify to the mapper which NewsLetter implementation to use ? The NewsLetterDefault implementation extends from MapProperties<String>: a class with a field "private Map<String, V> properties" and all kind of setter/getters for adding/removing a property. The NewsLetter interface extends from the corresponding "HasProperties<String>" interface. I guess that results in adding the ghost property ;), but no idea how ?

Comment: Did you try to add a `@JsonIgnore` to the problem property? Or am I misunderstanding what you are saying? Is there no property? Is that what you mean by "ghost"?

Comment: I can't put the '@JsonIgnore' on the map in the parent class as it comes from a shared project that has no Jackson dependency and I can't change that. I tried to exclude it in the child class with '@JsonIgnoreProperties' and '@JsonAutoDetect', but had no effect. I read about using a Mixin, but I wander if then it's not better to use my described solution? Or replacing '@JsonAnyGetter' with '@JsonValue' as that also seem to work. What do you tih

Comment: If `@JsonValue` works, I don't see any benefit in creating a mixin. I would just go with that

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to get a propper JSON, like this:

> ```
> {
>     "newsletter": {
>         "key1": "value1",
>         "key2": "value2",
>         "key3": "value3"
>     }
> }
> ```

(*notice the `,` as the delimiter instead of `;`*)

then you can use the following class to hold your JSON data:

```
class Preferences {
    @JsonProperty("newsletter")
    private Map<String, String> newsLetter;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Preferences{" + "newsLetter=" + newsLetter + '}';
    }
}
```

Here, you're not using the `NewsLetter` class anymore since you would need a nested key, like [Roman C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c) said in his answer. Just directly add the `Map` field to your `Preferences` class and it will work fine.

You can read your JSON like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(om.readValue(new File("example.json"), Preferences.class));
}
```

It would print:

> Preferences{newsLetter={key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}}

Comment: thanks for your solution. Sorry for the delimiter mistake, just corrected it. I tried this a fews days ago and that works fine. But I like to abstract the Newsletter stuff in his own class such that I can add other stuff like finders and other manipulation methods. With your solution the class Preferences and internals of the NewsLetter class become to dependent (to tightly coupled).

Comment: If you can't change the JSON, then the only way I know to still use Jackson ist to drop the map and add a field for each key in the `NewsLetter` class. Since this is pretty silly, I assume you need to drop Jackson instead :(. But I can suggest an different library.

Comment: I don't know the key/value pairs in the Newsletter, they are dynamic, not fixed, can change every moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how The JSON to Java conversion works

The first step is to create the Java class that would hold the JSON data. You already have one. Look at the json. You create an `Preferences` object to hold the
entire json. The json contains an `newsletter` element. You
create a Java Object of type `Newsletter` in the `Preferences` object. 
Create an instance of the `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` class. This is the class
that maps a JSON to a Java Object.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Then use the `readValue` method of the `ObjectMapper` to read. There are multiple versions of this method and you can use the method that takes in a
`String`. However, there are method that read from a `URL`, `File`, `InputStream`, `String` or a `ByteArray`.

The `ObjectMapper` caches serializers and deserializers so it would be a good idea to reuse an `ObjectMapper` instance for multiple
conversions
If you have an `String` then pass it to Jackson to convert it to Java Object.

```java
String str = "
    { \"newsletter\":
      {
        \"properties\": {
         \"key1\" : \"value1\",
         \"key2\" : \"value2\",
         \"key3\" : \"value3\"
      }
     }
   }";

//read json
Preferences preferences = mapper.readValue(str, Preferences.class);
//write json
mapper.writeValue(str, preferences);
```

You can use a tool that escapes json to a java string: http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

This tool produces the following result

```
{ \"newsletter\":\r\n          {\r\n            \"properties\": {\r\n             \"key1\" : \"value1\",\r\n             \"key2\" : \"value2\",\r\n             \"key3\" : \"value3\"\r\n          }\r\n         }\r\n        }
```

Comment: Like mentioned, it's a "snippet" and part of a much bigger json.

Comment: thanks for the details. I am aware of them. But how to solve my problem without changing the Json as I can't change it. Like mentioned in Tom his answer I prefer the current abstract relation Preference -> Newsletter.

Comment: If you aware of it why did you ask it? Deserialization from json won't work if a class doesn't have required properties, and json should have a valid format for deserializer to work.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer, because it helped me when I was looking for the solution how too easy parse json on the server, but can't upvote my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working.
I use

- @JsonValue to create JSON part of newsletter.
- @JsonCreator to create the NewsLetter instance with the map
  containing the key/value pairs.
- @JsonTypeInfo to indicate which implementation to use to create an
  NewsLetter instance.

The test run fine, both ways, with the above json snippet .
In Code (The Preferences class is the same as listed in the original question):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, defaultImpl = NewsLetterPreferencesDefault.class)
public interface NewsLetterPreferences  {
}

public final class NewsLetterPreferencesDefault {
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    @JsonCreator
    public NewsLetterPreferencesDefault(final Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties.
    }

    @JsonValue
    public Map<String, String> getAllProperties() {
        return this.properties;
    }
}
```

Is the way to do it? I never used @JsonTypeInfo before, so I hope it's correct. I will google some more examples with it. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Though this seems to be ok, I think it's overkill. There are simpler ways.

Comment: Sorry. I was to post an answer when I saw peeskillet's answer. That's the best way to do it.